# Breaking a line to a 2d pointer array in c, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, memory

I wrote the following code in order to break a line by ',' and put the data in 2d pointer array dynamically.

So if the line is:

> Hello, world, My name, is

The 2d pointer array will be:

> Hello
>
> world
>
> my name
>
> is

I'm a bit new to C so I'm not sure if the code is written well.

When parameters is the line I want to break.

```
char *parameters = "A line I want to break by, Hello";
char ** inputs;
int number = 1;
inputs = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char));
const char s[2] = ",";
char *token;
token = malloc(sizeof(parameters));
strcpy(token,parameters);
token = strtok(token, s);
while( token != NULL ) 
{
    inputs[number - 1] = malloc(sizeof(token));
    strcpy(inputs[number - 1],token);
    number++;
    inputs = (char **) realloc(inputs, sizeof(char)*(number+1));
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

For some reason it works ok for 1 or none ',' in line but for more its printing a very weird stuff.

For example:

If the line is

> Hello, world

The output will be:

> hello??
>
> world

It looks like a memory problem but I cant find it.
Also tips and better ways to solve it are welcome.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char));` allocates **one byte** of memory.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(token));` allocates only enough for a **pointer** not the string it is pointing to.

Comment: `char **` is not a 2D array nor a pointer to one! A pointer is not an array! And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general!

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(parameters));` is **unknown** as `parameters` is not shown.

Comment: Are you sure thats the prob? And if it is what should I change it too? @WeatherVane

Comment: Immediately after allocating 4 (perhaps 8) bytes of memory with `malloc(sizeof(token));` you try to cram the string data in there with `strcpy(inputs[number - 1],token);`

Comment: I don't get it @Olaf where is my prob?

Comment: I am I sure it is *the* prob? No there are a host of problems, but the first one is allocating only one byte of memory.

Comment: So change it to     malloc(sizeof(&token));?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145197/discussion-between-yonlif-and-weather-vane).

Comment: `malloc(strlen(token) + 1)`

Comment: @WeatherVane it allocates at least 1 byte, indeed, glibc malloc() for example allocates at minimum 8 bytes (and only multiples of 8)

Comment: double it by sizeof char?

Comment: What is a "prob"? This is an english speaking site.

Comment: It isn't english?

Comment: @Ctx so it might, but only one byte is guaranteed.

Comment: Can you please write your answers not in the comments? @WeatherVane

Comment: You too @Ctx please

Comment: @WeatherVane That's exactly what I wrote, isn't it?

Comment: @Ctx, no, you implied it's ok to assume there is more, or to assume that non-standard behaviour is portable.

Comment: @WeatherVane No, please read and comprehend my comment properly. "It allocates at least 1 byte" means exactly, one byte is guaranteed.

Comment: @Ctx, I don't know why you have gone off on this unhelpful tanget. `malloc(1)` was incorrect.

Comment: @WeatherVane Just improved a slightly inaccurate expression, that's all

Comment: @Ctx to be pedantic, it is not allocating 8 bytes, but ensuring that the pointer is suitably aligned. "7.20.3 Memory management functions ... **calloc**, **malloc**, and **realloc** ... The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object ... 7.20.3.3  ... the **malloc** function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by **size** and whose value is indeterminate."

Comment: @WeatherVane No, to be pedantic, the lower 3 bit of the chunk size are flags, this is the reason why it is a multiple of 8. This has nothing to do with alignment

Comment: That is an implementation detail.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, which leads to the fact, that glibc malloc indeed allocates 8 bytes if you try to allocate less, for example.

Comment: We are not going to agree on this.

Comment: @WeatherVane From libc malloc.c: "Minimum allocated size: 4-byte ptrs:  16 bytes    (including 4 overhead)" - "8-byte ptrs:  24/32 bytes (including, 4/8 overhead)" Hope that helps ;)

Comment: @Ctx well that does not look like "minimum 8 bytes" to me. By what mechanism does `malloc` inform the calling code how many bytes were allocated?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, indeed it's even 12/20/24 bytes, depending! malloc cannot inform the calling code how many bytes were allocated, that's why it's only safe to assume that the given number of bytes were allocated, when indeed it might have been more in almost all cases. An analysis of the in-memory structure can show the real number of bytes allocated, if someone is curious.

Comment: @Ctx which is why my original comment is correct. If `malloc(1)` does not return `NULL` the only information we have is that 1 byte was allocated.

Comment: @WeatherVane This is getting ridiculous... This is _not_ what you wrote, your wrote, that _only one byte is allocated_. _I_ wrote, that we know, that _at least_ one byte was allocated, but indeed, the most common implementations allocate more than that. Scroll up, it's all there. But I'll let it be good for now. Look, I even voted up your answer below. Friends?

Comment: @Ctx thank you - and yes I do know what you were saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating enough memory, for anything. Firstly

```
inputs = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

allocates only one byte of memory, where you want an array of pointers. So to get memory for the first element the code should be

```
inputs = malloc(sizeof(char*));
```

And then when you reallocate the array it is similar with

```
inputs = (char **) realloc(inputs, sizeof(char)*(number+1));
```

still only using byte size, not pointer size, and should be

```
inputs = realloc(inputs, sizeof(char*) * (number+1));
```

although it is better to assign to a temporary variable until you know the `realloc` was successfull. Notice too, I am not casting the return value from `malloc` or `realloc`.

Then there is the memory allocation for the token's data which you have as

```
inputs[number - 1] = malloc(sizeof(token));
```

which is not allocating memory for the token data, but just a pointer, and should be

```
inputs[number - 1] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
```

Having said that there is some clumsy use of `number - 1` and `number + 1` which might affect your algorithm. Better to bite the bullet and accept that in C indexing begins at `0` and not at `1`.

Finally can say nothing about the line

```
token = malloc(sizeof(parameters));
```

because we do not know what `parameters` is, but judging from the other allocations, is likely to be incorrect. But it *does* cause a memory leak: you later overwrite `token` and so cannot `free` its original memory.

Comment: Thanks!!! Its working now, When I will end to write all of it I will use your tips!